# Vite won't allow CORS (Vue3 application)

Tags: express, cors, vuejs3, vite

I am developing a Vue3 app with Vite as the bundler. The app is served from `localhost:5173`. The app communicates with an Express.js API, which is served from `localhost:3000`. This is the request code:

```
const req = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/book", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ bookId: 4 })
}).then(res => res.json())
```

This is working. But when I add a `Content-Type` header, I get a CORS error:

```
const req = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/book", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    body: JSON.stringify({ bookId: 4 })
}).then(res => res.json())
```

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/book' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

To get around this, I followed the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-cors) for enabling CORS, and here is the updated `vite.config.js`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
      preflightContinue: true
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

But the error persists. How do I fix this?

Comment: What does it have to do with HTTPS?

Comment: See MDN on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). CORS is essentially an authorization system and so requires SSL for a lot of it to work.

Comment: @WaisKamal One problem with your CORS config is that you're allowing the wrong Web origin (`http://localhost:3000`). The error message indeed indicates that your client's Web origin is `http://localhost:5173`; this is the one you should allow in your CORS config.

Comment: @jub0bs requests coming from `http://localhost:5173` are always same-origin relative to Vite, because that is the address from which it is serving the Vue app.

Comment: @WaisKamal AFAIU, your Vite server is accessible on `http://localhost:3000` and your Vue frontend is on `http://localhost:5173`. Correct? If not, please explain to me what I'm missing. But if I'm correct, you'll need to allow `http://localhost:5173` in your server's CORS configuration. Allowing all Web origins as you've done in your answer is one way of doing it, but you may want to restrict the list of allowed origins to the bare minimum.

Comment: No, the Vite server is serving the frontend (the Vue app) on `http://localhost:5173`, i.e. the Vite server and the frontend are running at the same origin:  `http://localhost:5173`. The Express server is the one running at ` `http://localhost:3000``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, so I would like to post an answer in case someone faces the same problem.

Apparently, the problem is that Vue is sending a preflight request *before* the actual request, and **only** if this request succeeds, then Vue will send the actual request.

The preflight request was failing not because Vite was blocking cross-origin requests (it allows such requests [by default](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-cors)), but rather because the Express server was blocking cross-origin requests. This causes the preflight request to fail together with the subsequent request.

The solution is to [enable CORS on the Express server](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html). For my case, since I am only doing it in development, I allowed all origins:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
```